# No actiongroup parameter in Add-AzWebtestAlertRule

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-monitoring

I want to create the AppInsights with Availability test (WebTest), and attach email alert rule to it using Azure Powershell. And I'd like to attach the already existing ActionGroup with needed email addresses to the alert rule.

According to latest Add-AzWebtestAlertRule method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azwebtestalertrule?view=azps-3.0.0), there is no ActionGroup parameter. However, in Azure portal we can attach the existing action group to the WebTest alert rule.
The Add-AzWebtestAlertRule has only the "Action" property which is of type `List`1[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.RuleAction]>]`, but it's not clear how to use that one.

Also, if take a look at [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-3.0.0), it does have the ActionGroup property and so we can attach action group to it.

So this is the confusion why one method has ActionGroup prop, and another one that seems similar, does not. Maybe there is a way to use the "Action" property to attach action group, but it's not clear how.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the command `Add-AzWebtestAlertRule` provides the property `action` . Its type is `` List`1[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.RuleAction] ``. We can use the property to ensure which action we do after meeting the rule condition. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azwebtestalertrule?view=azps-3.0.0).
[image]

Comment: That's not answering my question that ActionGroup parameter is not present even though the UI allow us to use action group. The mentioned "Action" parameter is not action group. The issue is posted on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10506